# HTML5 download attribute error handling

Tags: html, error-handling, download

In html5 i am trying to use download attribute , here is a sample code

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

If a link is invalid or forbidden it still downloads a forbidden html error page or some other error page. Instead is there a way to check if the header is 200 or download resource if only accessible/exists?

Comment: Are you allowed to use JavaScript to achieve the end result?

Comment: yes we can use javascript.. i am trying to see if a simplest way is available

Comment: Then it that case I would recommend using JavaScript to make an AJAX request to the link in question, and then in the `success` callback of the AJAX call, update the `href` and `download` attributes of the element in question.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem with this solution, for a PDF download:

```
const onDownloadClick = async (evt) => {
    const anchor = evt.target.parentNode;

    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/pdf',
            responseType: 'blob',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/pdf'
            }
        });

        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: 'application/pdf',
        });
        anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        anchor.download = 'filename.pdf';
        anchor.click();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Initially, the link does not have the download attribute. I just set it dynamically and simulate clicking on the link with JavaScript. For images, you just need a different header and blob type. `image/jpeg` would do it, i guess.

Comment: Works brilliantly, just make sure you also add `anchor.download` - otherwise browsers may block just `href` as an unwanted popup, especially in my case, as I specifically added `anchor.target = 'blank';` in order to open in a separate tab.